# How can I increase the value stored in count by one every time it is a multiple of 2?

Tags: javascript, count, increment

How can I increase the value stored in count by one every time it is a multiple of 2

I have a function that returns the value of i, it is initialized to 0 and it is auto-incrementing, that is, when i is a multiple of 2, the counter has to increases by 1

I try to do is that when i is a multiple of 2, the variable count has to increase in 1

This is the code I'm doing, could you tell me where my error is?

```
let count = 0;
        
if( i % 2  == 0){               
  count++;
  console.log(count);       
}else{

}
```

Comment: You're testing `i` but incrementing `count`

Comment: you should do if( count % 2 == 0)

Comment: i is a variable that is auto-incremented and initialized to 0

Comment: Then what's the point of `count` why don't you just compute it? like `count = Math.floor(i/2);` or `count = i >> 1`

Answer (score 2):

You should divide `count` by 2, not `i`

```
let count = 0;

if( count % 2 == 0){
    count++; console.log(count);    
}else{

}
```

By the way, your code only runs once. So it seems that your code lacks some sort of a loop. There needs to be a `for` or `while` loop.

**Update:**

based on your comments, I think your code should look like this:

```
let count = 0;
let i = 0;
// set a limit, for example 100
while(i < 100){
  i = updateI(); // get the new value for i
  if( i % 2 == 0)
  {
     count++; console.log(count);    
  }else{

  }
}
```

Comment: i is a variable that is auto-incremented and initialized to 0

Comment: @API in that case you need to edit your question. So you want to increment count when i is a multiple of 2? or count?

Comment: I have a function that returns the value of i, it is initialized to 0 and it is auto-incrementing, that is, when i is a multiple of 2, the counter increases by 1

Comment: increase count when i is a multiple of 2

Comment: @API updated my answer. It may give you an idea on how your code should be.

Comment: I try to make count increase by 1 every time i is a multiple of 2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the full script like this. it works fine

```js
let count = 0;
let i = 0;
while(i < 10){
  i++;
  if(i % 2 == 0){    
    count++
    console.log('even number',i, 'of',count);       
  }
}
```

Comment: I try to make count increase by 1 every time i is a multiple of 2

Comment: you can use `setInterval` code. read here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp